# Unable to locate Global asax file in web app VS2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm building a web application in visual studio 2012. I meet with error such as this

```
WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).
```

Therefore after googling, it says that i need to edit some parts in the global asax file. However, i'm not able to locate my global asax file when i create web app. I'm only able to find it when i create a website.

Answer (score 7):

The Global.asax file is not required. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is some info about that from Microsoft.

If you right click on your project and go to Add->New Item and open the wizard, you can select Web in the left box and Global Application Class in the right box it will automatically add Global.asax file in the Name box and you can create it easily. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add the global.asax yourself. Just right-click and use "Add New Item".

Comment: According to this website,     http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/465613/WebForms-UnobtrusiveValidationMode-requires-a
I need to delete certain codes from the global.asax. If i were to create a new global asax, why would they ask users to cancel out certain codes?

Comment: If you don't see a global.asax, then it's unlikely that global.asax contains any code for you to delete...

Comment: If it does not contain any code then how do i solve this error. I followed this website which asked me to delete certain information to get the program to run.

    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/465613/WebForms-UnobtrusiveValidationMode-requires-a